# If JS handles upload file on POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, post, file-transfer

I send some file by Ajax (POST)

and I would like to know what file's size already has been received by server in JS.

If its possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very vague question, so I'm going to assume two things

- you're using nodejs with express on the backend
- you're sending a file through formdata

So if those assumptions are correct you're going to need something to parse formdata on the backend I recommend `multer` which is a middleware for express that handles file uploads and makes the files available on `req.file` or `req.files`(if uploading multiple files)

so to check the size of the file that was passed to server you just need to todo
`req.file.size` and it should show you the filesize

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#api